# MySQL AND clause after OR clause is being ignored

Tags: mysql

I have the following prepared statement query:

```
 SELECT id FROM CustomerSettings WHERE id  >= ? OR displayNameType  = ? AND id  < ? LIMIT 5 OFFSET 1
```

The "id <" part of the query is ignored. Curiously, if I move the statement BEFORE the OR statement then it is correctly evaluated by the MySQL database engine. Is this expected behaviour seems rather odd. I have also tried putting the OR clause in brackets this unfortunately didn't work either; the AND clause immediately following the OR is still ignored.

Comment: It's hard to see exactly what result you are looking for. `AND` binds more tightly than `OR`, so MySQL parses yours as `WHERE id >= ? OR (displayNameType = ? AND id < ?)`  If that isn't what you want, then the alternative may not make sense `(id >= ? OR displayNameType = ?) AND id < ?` because `id` may not be able to meet both conditions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is due to [operator precedence](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/operator-precedence.html). `AND` binds before `OR` so your query is `WHERE (id >= ?) OR (displayNameType = ? AND id < ?)`. The order of things matters. I'd suggest using parentheses to make the order of `AND` and `OR` explicit.